# Why are rules after my .htaccess <If></If> ignored?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running a WordPress site, and I want to redirect http to https for some domains, so I have these .htaccess rules (Apache 2.4):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} in { 'secure.mydomain.com', 'ssl.mydomain.com' }">
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

This works fine for non-https domains (e.g. [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)). But the WordPress rules are not being applied to https://secure.mydomain.com or https://ssl.mydomain.com. When I use those domains, I get 404 errors. I don't get the 404 errors if I remove the IF statement. It's almost as if apache thinks the WordPress rules are wrapped in an else statement.

So, a simple question. What is wrong with these rules?

Comment: The hardest part of Apache configuration, IMHO, is always to try and find out in what exact order different modules involved perform their tasks. Not a single one of the examples given under https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples actually uses mod_rewrite directives inside the IFs, so I am wondering if there’s perhaps a good reason for that. I’d just use mod_rewrite functionality for this part, too, if I was you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CBroe's comment got me off onto the right path. [According to this blog](https://www.schakko.de/2019/10/20/conditional-redirect-from-http-to-https-within-apache-htacces-files/), `RewriteCond` is not supported inside an `<If>` block.

I need to rewrite the rule so either it only uses `RewriteCond`, or it only uses `<If>`. Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.mydomain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ssl\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} in { 'secure.mydomain.com', 'ssl.mydomain.com' } && %{HTTPS} == 'off'">
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>
```

Comment: oh this is in a `.htaccess` file... fwiw conventional wisdom is that if the domain and protocol are incorrect the request shouldn't reach Wordpress' webroot at all, that'd normally be achieved by having multiple virtual hosts, were only the 'right' one reaches Wordpress and the other(s) only redirect (ref https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html). That would eliminate the complexity in the question, and answer.

Comment: Yeah, vhosts might be an easier way to do this. Unfortunately I don’t have access to that on my host.